# Keycloak - How we can set identity provider for Azure AD along with profile pic url? just like google identity provider

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, keycloak

We have setup both Google and Azure SSO using keycloak. For Google we have setup a identity provider and add mappers to get profile picture.

[image: Identity providers]

We have mappers to get attributes for profile pic
[image]
[image]

Then we got profile pic url from Google response.
[image]

But Same thing I have followed for Azure. But I didn't get profile pic url in Azure response.
I have followed these steps https://blog.hcltechsw.com/versionvault/how-to-configure-microsoft-azure-active-directory-as-keycloak-identity-provider-to-enable-single-sign-on-for-hcl-compass/

**Is that possible to get profile pic url from Azure?** just like google.

Or else any alternative way to get profile pic url from Azure AD?

**Pls Share references or steps for Azure SSO with profile pic url.**